# Firebase Firestore Javascript array is empty even if it is not on console.log

Tags: javascript

I have this first function that fetches all the members uid from firebase:

where badgelist1 = ['firstname', 'secondname', 'thirdname']

var memuid = []

```
function getMemuid(){
    for (var i = 0; i < badgelist1.length; i++) {
    const getUid = firebase
     .firestore()
     .collection('users')
     .where('badgeNum', '==', badgelist1[i])
   getUid.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
   querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
   memuid.push(doc.data()['collectionId'].toString())
     })
   })
  }
console.log(memuid) -->> this prints out all the items in array with no problem
savetoFB()
}
```

and the second function to save the array to firebase is:

```
function savetoFB(){
 console.log(memuid) -->> still prints out all the items

  firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('schedule')
  .doc(collectionid)
  .set({
    memuid: memuid --->> but when saving theres nothing here
    })
   .then(ref => {
    console.log('added!')
      })
  }
```

[firebase ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvsxK.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test your code but you are making a request, so you have to wait until the request is finished and has the data for you using [async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) or call savetoFB() in the callback.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the async and await. It turns out that the for loop needs some time to finally set the items inside the array. The savetofb is getting called at the same time as the for loop.